# cannot use prisma client in next.js api routes

Tags: next.js, prisma

So i was successfully able to implement prisma with my node.js app but when i switch to next.js and try to use prisma in the API routes i run into errors

```
Error: Invalid `prisma.product.findMany()` invocation:

Authentication failed against database server at `localhost`, the provided database 
credentials for `user` are not valid.

Please make sure to provide valid database credentials for the database server 
at`localhost`.
```

My connection string is right because i got it to work with my node.js but problems arise with next.js

This is actually the second db i got this error with , tried Postgres first and now mysql

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default async function handle(req, res) {
  const products = await prisma.product.findMany();
  console.log(products)
}
```

Am i missing the point here or doing a silly mistake.

Comment: Is the environment variable defined for the database URL? Could you log and check if that's available?

Comment: Hello , thanks for reply, I was actually able to get the API route working this morning. I'm not sure what was happening but i think it had to do with percentage encoding the special characters but honestly not sure how it was just fixed when I started developing again.